# SQL Multiple Join on first table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do a big query with possibly a bad logic of construction.

I have three tables, the first table is a list of userId which I would like to use for construct my rsult,

The second table is a list of tasks, I need to link this table to the first one with userId equalty statement, (first.userId = second.userId)

The third one is an other list of tasks, I want to do the same statement (first.userId = third.userId) with an extra statement (first.isResp = 1)

```
First
-----
userId PK
isResp (bit) 

Second 
------
taskId PK
userId
value

third
-----
taskId PK
userId
value
```

How can I construct my query to get a good result?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Write your query and we can help. Make an effort.

Comment: I don't know how to do a beautiful presentation of table... give me a documentation and i will make it! of course

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This post has some good tips and tools for formatting a question. [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: I was tired when I write this post,
Big thank you to all answers, I'm sorry about that, 
My probleme was not well understand, and the solution is basic.

**If an admin see this post pleas close it**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with inner join and this answer is totally based on assumption

```
select a.userid,a.isResp,b.taskId,c.value from first a inner join second b
on a.userid=b.userid inner join third c
on b.userid=c.userid and b.taskid=c.taskid
```

Comment: I make a query exactly like this, I try with a LEFT JOIN too but the Third table is like discard of result.

Comment: do the left join with both table

Comment: Isn't this creating a lot more rows than OP desires? I'm guessing that both Second and Third return multiple rows per userId, which would create a cartesian product per userId.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see any logical relationship between Second and Third (both are one-to-many to First I'm guessing), I'm guessing you're looking to combine two resultsets. Is the following what you're looking for?

```
SELECT   F.userId, S.taskId, 'Tasks of Second' AS Origin, S.Value
FROM     First AS F
 JOIN    Second AS S
  ON     F.userId = S.userId

UNION ALL

SELECT   F.userId, T.taskId, 'Tasks of Third' AS Origin, T.Value 
FROM     First AS F
 JOIN    Third AS T
  ON     F.userId = T.userId
WHERE    F.isResp = 1
```

If not, as already commented, please provide us with additional information like samples, desired results and so on.